# Unable to launch springboot application without setting datasource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, datasource

I'm trying to launch my **SpringBoot** application without configuring DataSource prior to compilation. If I do this, indicating the parameters, the application works normally, but I want to pass them through the **JAVA_OPTS** parameter when I run a **docker** container. Like that:

```
docker run --network public --link pg --name tm -e JAVA_OPTS="-Ddatasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://pg:5432/ggal1701 -Ddatasource.user=postgres -Ddatasource.password=postgres" -p 9000:8080 worker
```

I've tried many of the options I've seen on Stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me.

**My build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'net.ltgt.gradle', name: 'gradle-apt-plugin', version: '0.6'
        classpath group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: spring_boot_version
        classpath group: 'org.springframework.build.gradle', name: 'propdeps-plugin', version: '0.0.7'
    }
}


plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.6.2"
}

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'propdeps'
defaultTasks 'bootRun'

bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'es.asd.GGAL1701.Application'
}

war {
    rootSpec.exclude("**/tomcat-*.jar")
    exclude("**/client")
    exclude("**/tmp")
    exclude("**/upload")
    from "dist"
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = 'es.asd.GGAL1701.Application'
    executable = true
}

bootRun {
    addResources = false
}

if (project.hasProperty('prod')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_prod.gradle'
} else {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_dev.gradle'
}

apply from: 'gradle/process_resources.gradle'

group = 'es.asd.GGAL1701'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

description = ''

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}


repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://asd-nexus.com/repository/maven-central/"
        credentials {
            username "asd"
            password "asd./"
        }
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "${nexusUrl}/repository/maven-releases/") {
                authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: "${nexusUrl}/repository/maven-snapshots") {
                authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
            }
        }
    }
}


repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    maven { url 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2' }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'

    //
    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'
    compile group: 'javax.el', name: 'javax.el-api', version: '3.0.0'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
    compile group: 'javax.transaction', name: 'javax.transaction-api', version: '1.2'
    compile group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'jsr250-api', version: '1.0'

    compile(group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'HikariCP', version: '2.6.3') {
        exclude(module: 'tools')
    }
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: postgresql_version

    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aspects', version: spring_framework_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: spring_framework_data_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core', version: spring_security_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: spring_security_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-data', version: spring_security_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: spring_security_version

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure', version: spring_boot_version

    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: hibernate_version
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-java8', version: hibernate_version
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: hibernate_version

    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.7.0'

    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-yaml', version: jackson_version
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: jackson_version
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: jackson_version
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-hibernate5', version: jackson_version
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: jackson_version

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.5'

    compile group: 'net.bull.javamelody', name: 'javamelody-core', version: '1.68.0'

    compile group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.3.2'

    // Envío de emails
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'

    // Generación de PDFs
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.5.10'
}

compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)

clean {
    delete "target"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.12'
}

task stage(dependsOn: 'bootRepackage') {
}
```

**My gradle.properties:**

```
rootProject.name=application
profile=dev
##
## Versiones de las dependencias comunes del proyecto
postgresql_version=9.4-1203-jdbc42
jackson_version=2.7.9
hibernate_version=5.2.10.Final
spring_boot_version=1.4.7.RELEASE
spring_framework_version=4.3.9.RELEASE
spring_framework_data_version=1.10.11.RELEASE
spring_security_version=4.1.4.RELEASE
systemProp.sonar.host.url=https://asd-sonarqube.ga
systemProp.sonar.login=asd
systemProp.sonar.password=asd./
systemProp.sonar.sources=src/main
nexusUrl=http://asd-nexus.ga
nexusUsername=asd
nexusPassword=asd./
#Para solucionar problema de lanzar sonarqube desde jenkins
org.gradle.daemon=false
#systemProp.sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar
#systemProp.sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
#systemProp.sonar.jdbc.password=sonar

##
## Configuraciones de GRADLE
##
## Below are some of the gradle performance improvement settings that can be used as required, these are not enabled by default
##
## The Gradle daemon aims to improve the startup and execution time of Gradle.
## When set to true the Gradle daemon is to run the build.
## TODO: disable daemon on CI, since builds should be clean and reliable on servers
## un comment the below line to enable the daemon
#org.gradle.daemon=true
## Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
## The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
## Default value: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
## un comment the below line to override the daemon defaults
#org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
## When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
## This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
## http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
## un comment the below line to enable parellel mode
#org.gradle.parallel=true
## Enables new incubating mode that makes Gradle selective when configuring projects.
## Only relevant projects are configured which results in faster builds for large multi-projects.
## http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:configuration_on_demand
## un comment the below line to enable the selective mode
#org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

**My application.yml:**

```
# ===================================================================
# Spring Boot configuration.
#
# This configuracion will be overriden by the Spring profile you use,
# for example application-dev.yml if you use the "dev" profile.
# ===================================================================

locale:
    default: es

server:
    port: 8080

spring:
    jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
        database: POSTGRESQL
        openInView: false
        show_sql: false
        generate-ddl: false
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
            naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
        properties:
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
            hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
            hibernate.current_session_context_class: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
    http:
      multipart:
        max-file-size: 20Mb
        max-request-size: 20Mb
    messages:
      basename: i18n/messages
    thymeleaf:
      mode: XHTML

properties:
    async:
        corePoolSize: 2
        maxPoolSize: 50
        queueCapacity: 10000
    security:
        authentication:
            jwt:
                secret: c2t3f0c5dXF6bV9tOV45X2RpdmlzYQ==
                # Token is valid 24 hours
                tokenValidityInSeconds: 86400
                tokenValidityInSecondsForRememberMe: 2592000
```

**My application-prod.yml:**

```
# ===================================================================
# Spring Boot configuration for the "prod" profile.
#
# This configuracion overrides the application.yml file.
# ===================================================================

spring:
    # Configuración de la BASE DE DATOS
    datasource:
        dataSourceClassName: org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
        url: jdbc:postgresql://pg:5432/ggal1701
        username: asd
        password: asd
        maximum-pool-size: 5

    application:
        url: http://localhost:8080
    profiles:
        active: prod
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: false
        livereload:
            enabled: false
server:
    compression:
        enabled: true
        mime-types: text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css, application/javascript, application/json
```

As I mentioned at the beginning, I have tried many of the alternatives that appear in StackOverflow, but when I don't configure spring.datasource in my application-prod.yml, I always get a bug similar to the following one:

```
mrnobody@mrnobody-UX301LAA:~/Escritorio/tfg/appserver$ sudo docker run --network public --link pg --name tm -e JAVA_OPTS="-Ddatasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://pg:5432/ggal1701 -Ddatasource.user=postgres -Ddatasource.password=postgres" -p 9000:8080 worker
02-May-2018 20:56:17.864 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.51
02-May-2018 20:56:17.867 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Apr 9 2018 21:20:15 UTC
02-May-2018 20:56:17.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.51.0
02-May-2018 20:56:17.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
02-May-2018 20:56:17.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.13.0-39-generic
02-May-2018 20:56:17.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
02-May-2018 20:56:17.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
02-May-2018 20:56:17.869 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_162-8u162-b12-1~deb9u1-b12
02-May-2018 20:56:17.869 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
02-May-2018 20:56:17.869 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
02-May-2018 20:56:17.869 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
02-May-2018 20:56:17.870 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
02-May-2018 20:56:17.870 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
02-May-2018 20:56:17.870 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Ddatasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://pg:5432/ggal1701
02-May-2018 20:56:17.870 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Ddatasource.user=postgres
02-May-2018 20:56:17.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Ddatasource.password=postgres
02-May-2018 20:56:17.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
02-May-2018 20:56:17.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
02-May-2018 20:56:17.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
02-May-2018 20:56:17.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
02-May-2018 20:56:17.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
02-May-2018 20:56:17.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
02-May-2018 20:56:17.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.16 using APR version 1.5.2.
02-May-2018 20:56:17.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
02-May-2018 20:56:17.882 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017)
02-May-2018 20:56:18.001 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
02-May-2018 20:56:18.010 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
02-May-2018 20:56:18.011 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 614 ms
02-May-2018 20:56:18.040 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
02-May-2018 20:56:18.041 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.51
02-May-2018 20:56:18.066 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
02-May-2018 20:56:21.589 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
20:56:21.802 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN es.enxenio.GGAL1701.ApplicationWebXml - No Spring profile configured, running with default configuracion
20:56:22.446 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.exception-conversion-word]
name [LOGGING_EXCEPTIONCONVERSIONWORD]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [LOGGING_EXCEPTIONCONVERSIONWORD] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [LOGGING_EXCEPTIONCONVERSIONWORD].
20:56:22.456 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [LOGGING_EXCEPTIONCONVERSIONWORD]
20:56:22.456 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [LOGGING_EXCEPTIONCONVERSIONWORD] threw NamingException with message: Name [LOGGING_EXCEPTIONCONVERSIONWORD] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [LOGGING_EXCEPTIONCONVERSIONWORD].. Returning null.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.7.RELEASE)

2018-05-02 20:56:22.956  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] es.enxenio.GGAL1701.ApplicationWebXml    : Starting ApplicationWebXml on c72e1d8684c7 with PID 1 (/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes started by root in /usr/local/tomcat)
2018-05-02 20:56:22.958 DEBUG 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] es.enxenio.GGAL1701.ApplicationWebXml    : Running with Spring Boot v1.4.7.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.9.RELEASE
2018-05-02 20:56:22.959  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] es.enxenio.GGAL1701.ApplicationWebXml    : The following profiles are active: prod
2018-05-02 20:56:23.096 DEBUG 1 --- [kground-preinit] org.jboss.logging                        : Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider found via system property
2018-05-02 20:56:25.745 DEBUG 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] net.bull.javamelody                      : spring interceptor initialized
2018-05-02 20:56:25.757 DEBUG 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] net.bull.javamelody                      : spring interceptor initialized
2018-05-02 20:56:25.758 DEBUG 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] net.bull.javamelody                      : spring interceptor initialized
2018-05-02 20:56:27.019  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] e.enxenio.GGAL1701.config.WebConfigurer  : Web application configuracion, using profiles: [prod]
2018-05-02 20:56:27.020 DEBUG 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] e.enxenio.GGAL1701.config.WebConfigurer  : Registering Caching HTTP Headers Filter
2018-05-02 20:56:27.021  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] e.enxenio.GGAL1701.config.WebConfigurer  : Web application fully configured
2018-05-02 20:56:27.056  WARN 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [es/enxenio/GGAL1701/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2018-05-02 20:56:27.062  WARN 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
2018-05-02 20:56:27.198 ERROR 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method entityManagerFactory in es.enxenio.GGAL1701.config.DatabaseConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' in your configuration.

02-May-2018 20:56:27.199 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:755)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:731)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [es/enxenio/GGAL1701/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)


02-May-2018 20:56:27.202 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:759)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)


02-May-2018 20:56:27.204 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war has finished in 9,137 ms
02-May-2018 20:56:27.212 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs
02-May-2018 20:56:27.267 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished in 55 ms
02-May-2018 20:56:27.270 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples
02-May-2018 20:56:27.535 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples has finished in 265 ms
02-May-2018 20:56:27.535 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
02-May-2018 20:56:27.566 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has finished in 31 ms
02-May-2018 20:56:27.566 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager
02-May-2018 20:56:27.588 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 22 ms
02-May-2018 20:56:27.593 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
02-May-2018 20:56:27.631 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
02-May-2018 20:56:27.651 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 9639 ms
```

Comment: Did you try using place holders in YAML file like this `url:${datasource.jdbcUrl}`

Comment: Thank you so much @VenuDuggireddy. Do you mean setting it that way in my application-prod.yml? How I would invoke this in doing gradle war? The problem is that if I don't set these parameters at the time of compiling (gradle war), even if I pass it on later as JAVA_OPTS, the application will not start. With a totally different application using Maven I have had no problems.

Comment: Why do you have a `DatabaseConfiguration`? Looks like you are working around Spring Boot instead of using it. Also don't pass it as `JAVA_OPTS` just pass the properties as Docker environment variables instead and use `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME` etc. Don't reinvent your own.

Comment: Can you try passing as environment variables instated of JAVA_OPTS like this `docker run --network public --link pg --name tm -e DATASOURCE.JDBCURL=jdbc:postgresql://pg:5432/ggal1701 -e DATASOURCE.USER=postgres -e DATASOURCE.PASSWORD=postgres -p 9000:8080 worker` and also update the application-prod.yml and set the active profile to `prod`

Comment: Thank you very much @M.Deinum I don't understand what you mean exactly by not having a database configuration. If I don't put it on, the application will fail directly when I launch it. I have tried commenting on the datasource part of my application-prod.yml and it doesn't work either. 

Which parts of my configuration files should I skip? I don't know where to modify my configuration files so I don't have to enter that information when compiling and take the environment variables when I do docker run. Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you again @VenuDuggireddy. I have also tried:

`docker run --network public --network --link pg --name tm -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_JDBCURL=jdbcc:postgresql://pg:5432/ggal1701 -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_USER=postgres -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres -p 9000:8080 worker`

But always the same result. I have to modify the configuration files, but I don't know exactly what.

Comment: Have you set the profile as `prod`? If you look the log file is using default profile ie., `applicaiton.yaml` file `20:56:21.802 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN es.enxenio.GGAL1701.ApplicationWebXml - No Spring profile configured, running with default configuracion`. Update the gradle.properties profile to `prod` and give it a try

Comment: You are trying to outsmart Spring Boot. You are building 2 artifacts (according to your gradle file) and basically go live with untested code. You should package stuff in your application or provide them as environment variables. Spring Boot already configures a `DataSource` and if you don't need more then one you don't need to include it.

Comment: Yes @VenuDuggireddy, I have set the profile as prod. But I always get the same result. I provide a pastebin because the size of the comment does not allow me to show what I want: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/2aicAVv0).Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum , I'm just building an artifact, I have two profiles with two different conditions that if one applies, the other doesn't apply. The settings are in properties-prod.yml and properties-dev.yml. I already put the website into production this way without any problem, but now I'm trying to launch it in a pipeline using docker containers, so I'm interested in not having hardcoded this configuration.

Comment: With a Maven application I previously had no problems, but in this one, different, I am encountering a wall. The tests (unit, integrity, regression, load, functional,...) I am not launching them now so as not to lengthen the process while I test all this on docker. Thank you again very much for your time @M.Deinum. See if I can make this work; It's taking me a while.

Comment: No you are building 2 artifacts (1 for different environments at least that is what your gradle build tells me). Also there is nothing hardcoded as you can provide docker environment variables. (I strongly suggest a read on Spring Boot and how property resolution works).

Comment: I add my profile_prod.gradle to the next pastebin, in case it helps:[profile_prod.gradle](https://pastebin.com/rPPbYpBn)

Comment: I really appreciate your help @M.Deinum , but right now I don't know if you're criticizing my setup because you see something wrong or you just want to tell me to read the documentation. I've read it before to mount the applications, only I'm stuck at this point to run it on docker. I think that's what the site is for, to ask questions that we're stuck in, providing as much information as possible. I've been consulting information for several days trying to work this out. I'm not looking for someone to say, "Put this here." But I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: I'm doing both I guess. The fact is you are trying to be smarter then the frameworks you are using by building an artifact per environment (at least that is what your `build.gradle` is telling me). If you are doing things as one would do with a Spring Boot application passing properties as Docker environment variables should be all that is needed. If that isn't working you are doing things in a way that breaks the way Spring Boot is working. (Which I really suspect because of the way you are building things and the fact you included your own `DatabaseConfiguration`).

Comment: Thank you very much again, I will try to find out what settings on the spring configuration I should remove and then pass it on as an environment variable; because I'm not sure exactly what to remove. New suggestions are still welcome from any user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **two choices, both works correctly**:

The **first** is to pass the values as JAVA_OPTS as follows (you are going through the parameters wrong):

```
docker run \
    --network public \
    --link pg \
    --name tm \
    -e JAVA_OPTS= \
        "-Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://pg:5432/ggal1701
         -Dspring.datasource.username=postgres \
         -Dspring.datasource.password=postgres" \
    -p 9000:8080 worker
```

The ***second*** is to pass the values as environment variables as follows (your mistake is the absence of quotes):

```
docker run \
    --network public \
    --link pg \
    --name tm \
    -e DATASOURCE_JDBC_URL="jdbc:postgresql://pg:5432/ggal1701" \
    -e DB_USERNAME="postgres" \
    -e DB_PASSWORD="postgres" \
    -p 9000:8080 worker
```

Remember to specify these parameters in your configuration to use this second option. In the first one you don't have to configure anything directly.

As part of the devOps culture I never recommend hardcoding the settings and opting for the second option while it is intended for that purpose. They both have to work for you, and if you don't, you have some other mistake.

What you say about the **hikariPool** error is only a consequence of the datasource failure. Try one of these two ways and, in my professional opinion, opt for the second.

I leave you a good tutorial: [Spring-boot tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)

Comment: If by `specify these parameters in your configuration` you mean doing something like `spring.datasource.url=${DATASOURCE_JDBC_URL}`, then this step is not necessary if the env variables are named `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`, `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME`, and `SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD`, making the external configuration even less intrusive

Answer (score 1):

If your task is to pass jdbc url as a parameter during container startup there is not need to do it through `DatabaseConfiguration`. It can be done fairly simpler using placeholders in your configuration and environment variables in docker-run command.

Define placeholders in the configuration:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${JDBC_URL}
    username: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
    password: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```

And run the container like this:

```
docker run \
    --network public \
    --link pg \
    --name tm \
    -e JDBC_URL="jdbc:postgresql://pg:5432/ggal1701" \
    -e DATABASE_USERNAME="postgres" \
    -e DATABASE_PASSWORD="postgres" \
    -p 9000:8080 worker
```

Note: docker link is deprecated functionality, you'd probably want to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Java properties should work according to the [Spring Boot Externalized Configuration Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). Might that be that you're not using the right name for the java properties?

From your production properties I see, for instance, that the property for the database URL is spring.datasource.url:

```
spring:
    # Configuración de la BASE DE DATOS
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://pg:5432/ggal1701
```

However you passing through the following Java Property:

```
-Ddatasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://pg:5432/ggal1701
```

I think instead you should use:

```
-Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://pg:5432/ggal1701
```

Another suggestion that always worked for me is to use environment variables instead of java properties. You can was them with equal simplicity to your Docker:

```
-e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://pg:5432/ggal1701
```